# Reverse Modulus Operator with given condition

Tags: c, math, reverse, modulus

I have an equation:

```
x^2 mod p = z ;
```

`p` and `z` are given. `x`,`p` and `z` are positive integers and **MAX** value of `x` is given (say **M**). `p` is **prime**. How can i calculate (multiple possible values) `x` when `p` and `z` are known ?

**UPDATE:**

I found solution here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/848062/reverse-modulus-operator-with-given-condition/848106#848106

Comment: The question seems to be off-topic as it is about pure mathematics and not programming-related. Furthermore, if `p` is not a prime number, the equation might yield more than one solution. For instance, if `p = 4` and `z = 2`, `x = 0` and `x = 2` are solutions.

Comment: For primes `p`, this might be what you are looking for: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cipolla%27s_algorithm. But I agree that the question is off-topic for this site. http://math.stackexchange.com might be better suited.

Comment: @Codor `P` is prime. I am more interesting in programmatic approach rather than mathematical  explanation that's why i posted it here.

Comment: If you are asking for code then (according to http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) it is expected that you include your attempted solutions.

Comment: @MartinR I am not looking for code but programmatic approach. What i means is mathematical approach may include some very complex mathematical function that is very difficult to code but if any approach that is not so difficult to code.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about maths (try http://math.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @dream_machine-Kindly check my answer and comment if satisfied or unsatisfied! I have optimized more using Martin R's valuable comment!

Comment: [Tonelli-shanks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli-Shanks_algorithm) for the win.

Answer (score 0):

if `x^2 mod p = z` 
then `x^2 = n*p + z` for some integer n 
with p and z known, substitute integer values for n to find x

Answer (score 0):

I don't why Santosh was downvoted,but his reasoning is correct!

```
As x^2 mod p=z   --->>    x^2=n*p+z   // for some integer n.
```

As you have `p` and `z` as known in your hands,you can individually check `if x^2 mod p=z` as shown below in the code and then find x(or rather equate the value of x) :-

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {   //main-method
     int x,p,z,xMAX=10;     // as per your condition
     p=13;                         // assigned p a prime positive integer value
     z=10;                         // assigned z a positive integer value
     for(x=0;x<=xMAX;x++){
      int sq=(int)Math.pow(x,2);    // squrare of x for each loop        
          if(sq%p==z){               // comparing square-value modulus prime value with value of z to be equal
           System.out.println("One value of x possible is "+x);   // if matches,you have one solution
          }
          else continue;
     }
   }
```

Sorry as the code is in `Java`,but I have mentioned `comments` in the code to identify each section. Also,this is very `complicated algorithm` as one can have a `better algorithm` for it,I guess! But,the output is working fine and is correct!

Output as per code :-

```
One value of x possible is 6 
One value of x possible is 7
```

Comment: Your answer is "Try all values of x until you find a solution". This is sensible for "small" values of xMAX, but for "large" values (e.g. in the range 2^60) this would be extremly slow and there are better algorithms (see my link above). - Also, instead of iterating over all possible values of n, you could just test `if ((x * x) % p == z)`.

Comment: @MartinR-Yeah,I went through your link.But,I couldn't carry through it as I couldn't grasp properly and also the example given there was irrelevant as per this question's context. And,I already stated in my answer that my code is slow and complicated algo,OP better need to search for fast algo.But,also, it depends on what he was trying to achieve,it worked fine with small data values,BUT surely not an optimal one!!

Comment: @MartinR-Also,I doubt OP has stated that only positive integers are allowed,and I guess 2^60 is too large to fit in any programming language's integer range!

Comment: @MartinR--And yeah,thanks for pointing at `if ((x * x) % p == z)` condition,now it's a bit more optimized,THANKS!